# How can we get the line range before another line range?

Tags: swift, uitextview

I use this code to get the current line range:

```
extension UITextView {
    var currentLineRange: NSRange {
        let nsText = self.text as NSString
        let currentRange = nsText.lineRange(for: self.selectedRange)
        return currentRange
    }
}
```

How can I get the line range before another one, like :

```
func getLineRangeBefore(_ lineRange: NSRange) -> NSRange {
//...
}
```

Comment: So given a range `r`, you want the range of characters of the previous line of the lines containing `r`?

Comment: @Sweeper, yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to get the line *start* of the range, then find the line range of the position before the line start:

```
extension NSString {
    func getLineRangeBefore(_ lineRange: NSRange) -> NSRange? {
        var lineStart = 0
        getLineStart(&lineStart, end: nil, contentsEnd: nil, for: lineRange)
        if lineStart == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return self.lineRange(for: NSRange(location: lineStart - 1, length: 0))
    }
}
```

Note that this should return an optional `NSRange` because the range could be contained by the first line, in which case there is no line before it.

Comment: Thanks!, if I want to get the line range "after" another , what condition should I add to lineEnd ?

Comment: @HassanTaleb You mean what goes in the `if`? If it's the last line, `lineEndIndex` would be equal to the length of the string ("index of the first character past the terminator of the line containing the end of `aRange`" as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415111-getlinestart) says).